# how to deploy MEAN stack app on AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I'm trying to deploy my mean stack app on AWS using elastic beanstalk but there doesn't seem to be a tutorial good enough that can help me through it.

I would also like to know if I should really deploy it on elastic beanstalk or Lightsail?

Can you share any articles, videos or anything good enough to help me. It will be helpful to a lot of people.

Angular Version : 7

Node Version: 10.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elastic beanstalk will be the option for production while you can use light sail for testing dev enviroment

now if we talk about the deploying Mean stack app

Open Elastic Bean stalk console and you will get option to choose Webserver

Choose web server with apache, tomcat, nginx, configure it as per your requirement

at last you will get option for upload your application

Upload your app using zip file (if dist folder is output then direct deploy dist in elastic beanstalk)

Comment: How I can deploy on lightsail?

Comment: open aws console go into light sail ...create instance choose OS, choose Region choose Application type wordpress, Mean etc and you can easily deploy now your app

Comment: 1 . instance will be set first time India if you are in india you can change it. 2. choose image type (linux and windows).  3. choose OS (linux) or OS + APP (linux + Mean) 4. choose instance plan (for pricing and free trail) you are good to go.....

Comment: I managed to upload on Elastic Beanstalk but I'm not able to connect with my MongoDB, can you help with this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241989/how-to-connect-mongodb-to-mean-app-deployed-in-aws-on-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: mongo db is online ? i mean where ?

Comment: I have it online on mlab

Comment: Using a different environment on dev and production is bad advice. Your production environment should be an exact match to your dev/testing environment to ensure you can actually "test" how your application will behave in production!