# How to connect mongoDB to MEAN app deployed in AWS on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying an app for the first time and I have deployed my MEAN App on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk but I haven't used the terminal to do so.

Now, I want to connect MongoDB with my deployed app.

Probably we need to connect to dynamoDB for Mongo database in AWS. Right?

And I would also like to know if I can use mlab database here instead?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html

Comment: .https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html

Comment: I don't see any tables when I open tables page in Dynamo console

Comment: you have to start making tables in dynamo db ...initially  no table will be there

Comment: And how it will be connected to my app?

Comment: did you checked first two link i have shared in comment ?